# Finding a reaction norm in R using logistic regression with binomial errors

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, interpretation

I am trying to calculate 'reaction norms' for a fish species. This is essentially the length at which the probability that a fish become mature equals 50% for a particular age class.

I know I have to use a logistic regression model with binomial errors but I can't work out how to calculate this from the summary outputs or plot the regression successfully!

I have a data set that has: 'age' classes in (1,2,3,4,5,6),'Lngth' data in mm and 'Maturity' data (Immature/Mature - 0/1).

I am running a glm as follows

```
Model<-glm(Maturity~Lgnth, family=binomial(logit))
```

This however does not take into account the different age classes (I would really like to avoid creating whole new data sets for each age classes as I have multiple year ranges to test).

doing this below doesn't specify the individual age group, or can this be worked out from the summary stats?

```
Model<-glm(Maturity~Lgnth+age, family=binomial(logit))
```

And even so, I do not understand how I interpret the summary output to give me a length at which the probability of being mature equals 50%, along with the standard errors of this figure.

I also can't quite get the code right to plot this. Ideally id have one plot with lngth along the x axis, probability along the y and six lines/curves representing each age classes.

I would really appreciate any help any one could provide! I know this can all be achieved but I am really struggling.

Cheers

Comment: any chance you can post some sample data? the `dose.p` function in the `MASS` package could come in handy for some of your questions ... and you might be interested in the model `Maturity~Lgnth*factor(age)`, or `lme4::lmList(Maturity~Lngth|age,family="binomial",data)`

Comment: cheers @BenBolker
I don't know the best way to post it,I'll post as much as I can and hope it's useful
`3986 obs. of  3 var
     Lngth:int  290 255 285 295 300
     age: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 6 6 6 5 5 5 ...
 Maturity: Factor w/ 2 levels "Immature","Mature": 2 2 2 `
`age
  Maturity      1       2       3     4    5    6
  Immature 2179  879   45    6    0    0
  Mature      6       549  224  70   22    6`

I am now using this model which seems to be okay?
`mylogit <- glm(Maturity ~ Lngth + age, data = clupea.data, family = "binomial")`

Comment: @BenBolker. Sorry the above is a mess! 
I think I'm getting there though. Once I have run the above glm how would  I find out the Length at which the probability (of each age class) becoming mature equals 50%? when I use dose.p it gives me all the ages combined. How do I/can I isolate each age class?